# Having Trouble With WPF Layout with user controls

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, dockpanel

I'm currently trying to get three user controls to work together, in place i have a dock panel which I am adding too. However I cant get the layout perfect, I would prefer to not add user control 1 within user control 2.

[image: Example of layout]

**Edit:** Imagine that the image is spelt Achieve and not Acheive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want Control 1 to be *above* Control 2 and not be contained in it, put them in a grid and give Control 1 a higher ZIndex:

```
<Grid>
    <Control1 Grid.ZIndex="2" />
    <Control2 Grid.ZIndex="1" />
    <Control3 Grid.ZIndex="1" />
</Grid>
```

[Here is the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex.aspx) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do that in DockPanel without the ugly margin manipulation. 1 and 2 should be in a Canvas:

```
 <Canvas x:Name="canvas">
        <Grid>
            <!-- usercontrol 1--> 
            <TextBlock Text="1"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
        <DockPanel Background="Transparent"
                    Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=canvas}" 
                    Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=canvas}">
             <!-- usercontrol 2-->  
            <TextBlock Text="2" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </DockPanel>
 </Canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I can add them to the canvas, however I'm having difficulties adding them to the correct position. `Canvas.SetTop(m,1000);` i tried setting before and after the children.add.